# Deploy python script on Synology NAS server

Tags: python, heroku, nas, synology

I'm considering a suggestion to buy a Synology NAS server DiskStation DS720+:
https://www.synology.com/de-de/products/DS720+#specs

to run my python scripts or deploy web apps.
I am currently using heroku free account to deploy a web app.
I can't explain, why my web app delivers wrong output on heroku but works completely fine on my local computer.
No error message when deploying on heroku, eventhough the output is wrong.

Since I know nothing about NAS server, I want to ask if following tasks are possible with the diskstation:

1. Deploying Python Script and Web App (with Dash and Plotly as backbone)
2. Hosting dynamic website, not static website (like github pages)

Please pardon me, if these are silly questions, since this area is new for me.
The idea that these are possible and that I have my own cloud server is quite tempting.

Is there a better and more economical option for these purpose?

Thank you in advance for any inputs. Best regards, Gunardi Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model you linked [supports Docker](https://www.synology.com/de-de/dsm/packages/Docker), so that would probably be the easiest way to host dynamic websites such as Plotly dashboards.

However, if your apps are not generating the desired output when you run them on a machine other than your local computer then running them on a NAS might not work, either.

EDIT: Rereading your question, I would not suggest buying a Synology NAS if your primary use case is a web server. They are trimmed down for ease of use, but they come with their own set of limitations.
Depending on how resource intensive your applications are you might want to look at an Intel NUC or even a Raspberry Pi. If you plan to use the Synology's other features [(file sharing, multi media, …)](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm) however, they are a great product.

Comment: From Intel NUC or Raspberry Pi, which one should I use? For more resource intensive, Intel NUC? Any other factors I should consider if the main goal are the two listed tasks?Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing the profile of the scripts and web apps you'd like to run. Generally, a NUC is more powerful than a Raspberry Pi thanks to its active cooling and beefier processor, but at the same time more power hungry, and way more expensive. If you enjoy tinkering and would like to learn the ropes around Linux, I suggest you try a Pi first. Have you looked into other cloud providers such as [Linode](https://www.linode.com)?

Comment: Also, if my answer was helpful to you, would you mind giving it an upvote or even mark it as the correct answer, since I answered your original question? Thank you!